# Get list of SharePoint WebParts using Get-PNPWebPart

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online I have create an out of the box site and added a couple of WebParts. I want to get the list of the WebParts and add them to other sites.

I'm using the command `Get-PNPWebPart` to get the WebParts from the site.

This is the code I have tried.

```
$user = "[username]"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "[password]" -AsPlainText -Force

$credentials = New-Object –TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" –ArgumentList $user, $password
 
$siteURL = "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/Sites/[site name]"
 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $credentials

$serverRelativePageUrl = "/sites/[site name]/SitePages/Home.aspx"

$webparts = Get-PNPWebPart -ServerRelativePageUrl $serverRelativePageUrl

foreach($webpart in $webparts)
{
    Write-Host "WebPart title:" $webpart.WebPart.Title
}
```

When I run this I don't get any errors but the `$webparts` variable is empty.

Why is the `$webParts` variable empty when I try to get the list of WebParts from the SharePoint site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-PnPWebPart is not valid for getting web parts in Modern Page(classic page will work).

Instead, please use the code snippet below to get web parts in Modern Site Home.aspx:

```
$user = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force

$credentials = New-Object –TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" –ArgumentList $user, $password
 
$siteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/JerryModernTeam"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $credentials


$page=Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Home.aspx"



$webParts = $page.Controls  
#if there are more than one webparts  
foreach($webpart in $webParts) {  
    Write - Host "WebPart Id "  
    $webpart.InstanceId  
    Write - Host "Title "  
    $webpart.Title  
}
```

Reference:

[Add, Remove, And Get All Web Parts From Modern Site Page Using PnP PowerShell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/add-remove-and-get-all-webparts-from-modern-site-page-using-pnp-powershell)